# Puzzle: find the weight of each penguin

Tags: combinatorics, puzzle

5 penguins are weighed on a scale in pairs. The zookeeper records the weight of each pair of penguins. They are 16, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 26, and 27 pounds. What is the weight of each penguin?

Since they are weighed in pairs, each penguin is weighed four times.

So the sum of the weights of the five penguins is

$$(16+18+19+20+21+22+23+24+26+27)/4=54$$

However, I don't know how to continue from there to find the weight of each penguin.

Comment: I suggest you next determine what must be the combined weight of the lightest $2$ penguins, and that of the heaviest $2$ penguins.

Comment: Extending @JohnOmielan's idea, the problem is immediately resolved by considering the heaviest three as $a < b < c,$ where $a$ is known, and $(b + c)$ is known.  Then, because $(27 - 26)$ is known, so is $[(b+c) - (a+c)]$.  This allows you to deduce the value of $b$, which then conquers the problem.  Note also, because the listed weights are $10$ distinct numbers, none of the penguins can have the same weight.

Comment: From Dudeney, Amusements in Mathematics: 101.—THE TRUSSES OF HAY.

Farmer Tompkins had five trusses of hay, which he told his man Hodge to weigh before delivering them to a customer. The stupid fellow weighed them two at a time in all possible ways, and informed his master that the weights in pounds were 110, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 120, and 121. Now, how was Farmer Tompkins to find out from these figures how much every one of the five trusses weighed singly?

Comment: Very similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/574739/42969

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let the penguins' weights in pounds, in increasing order, be $w_1$, $w_2$, $w_3$, $w_4$ and $w_5$. You've already shown that

$$w_1 + w_2 + w_3 + w_4 + w_5 = 54 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

The combined weight of the $2$ lightest penguins is the smallest recorded value, while the combined weight of the $2$ heaviest penguins is the largest recorded value, i.e.,

$$w_1 + w_2 = \color{red}{16}, \; \; w_4 + w_5 = \color{blue}{27} \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Next, \eqref{eq1A} minus the sum of the $2$ expressions in \eqref{eq2A} gives

$$w_3 = 54 - (\color{red}{16} + \color{blue}{27}) = \color{green}{11} \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

The second smallest recorded weight must be of the lightest penguin and the third lightest one so, by also using \eqref{eq3A} and the LHS of \eqref{eq2A}, we have

$$w_1 + w_3 = 18, \; \; w_1 = 18 - \color{green}{11} = 7 \; \; \to \; \; w_2 = \color{red}{16} - 7 = 9 \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

Similarly, as [user2661923's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4589701/puzzle-find-the-weight-of-each-penguin#comment9664163_4589701) basically suggests, the second largest recorded weight must be of the third heaviest penguin and the heaviest one so, by also using \eqref{eq3A} and the RHS of \eqref{eq2A}, we then get

$$w_3 + w_5 = 26, \; \; w_5 = 26 - \color{green}{11} = 15 \; \; \to \; \; w_4 = \color{blue}{27} - 15 = 12 \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

Thus, $w_1 = 7$, $w_2 = 9$, $w_3 = \color{green}{11}$, $w_4 = 12$ and $w_5 = 15$. We've already shown how the $2$ smallest and $2$ largest recorded weights come from the penguins' weights, with the remaining ones being $19 = 7 + 12 = w_1 + w_4$, $20 = 9 + \color{green}{11} = w_2 + w_3$, $21 = 9 + 12 = w_2 + w_4$, $22 = 7 + 15 = w_1 + w_5$, $23 = \color{green}{11} + 12 = w_3 + w_4$, and $24 = 9 + 15 = w_2 + w_5$.